# Certificate Prompt Issue in Firefox: Continual Requests Despite Selecting 'Remember this Decision'

Tags: authentication, ssl, firefox, certificate

I'm having an issue with Firefox where it doesn't remember my certificate choice when trying to access my company's RavenDB host. Each time I navigate to the site, it asks me to select the certificate again, even though I have chosen it literal seconds ago and ticked the `Remember this Decision` checkbox.
When I navigate to the certificates settings and look in the '`Authentication Decisions`' tab both the 'certificate name' and 'certificate number' for the host appear as `(unavailable)`. This issue seems to be specific to Firefox, as I don't encounter this problem when using Microsoft Edge. Has anyone experience this before?

I am on a MacBook M2 Pro.

I have tried to open the session in an incognito tab, in case firefox was trying to use another certificate.

Furthermore I have made sure that the certificate is not the issue since it works in Edge.